# How to split the page 50/50 with a picture and a div with text?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

im trying to replicate a structure i saw on another website  (https://fahertybrand.com/pages/about-mike-and-alex if u scroll down past the video and profiles) where the page is split 50/50 with a picture (which is responsive and doesnt change native size when the page is resized). I am also using material ui's grid system, which is like css flexbox. Read another stackoverflow saying to use a div with background-image, but not having much luck. Would love any help fixing this solution or trying another (with something like an img tag).

here is what i have so far

```
<Grid container spacing={0}>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
                    <div className="fill">
                        <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${stock1})`}}/>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
                <div className="missionHeader " name="aboutus">
                    <h1>WHAT WE STAND FOR</h1>
                        <p>{standFor}</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

and fill class has only prop of background-size: cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      <Grid
        container
        justify='center'
        alignItems='center'
      >
        <Grid item xs={9} sm={7} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
       <img src="your image url" /> //give the image 100% width
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={9} sm={7} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
          your text content here
  
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

here is a code sandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/new-rain-ei49v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Literally made this so much harder on myself. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `img` tag and adding

```
img: {
    maxWidth: '100%',
  }
```

so that the img doesn't overflow it'sparent size

working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-f2k7b?file=/demo.js